# why pdfjs not show the pdf chinese characters when rendered pdf to cavas image

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf.js

I am using this code to render the fisrt page of pdf to a image using pdfjs `"pdfjs-dist": "^3.9.179"`:

```
const initPdf = async (pdfUrl: string) => {
    setPdfUrl(pdfUrl);
    const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
    pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = window.location.origin + '/pdf.worker.min.js';
    const pdf = await pdfJS.getDocument(pdfUrl).promise;
    const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
    if (!canvas) return;
    const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
    const renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
    renderTask.promise.then(function () {
      const textContent = page.getTextContent();
      return textContent;
    }).then(function (textContent: string) {
      const textLayer = document.querySelector(".textLayer") as HTMLDivElement;
      textLayer.style.left = canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
      textLayer.style.top = canvas.offsetTop + 'px';
      textLayer.style.height = canvas.offsetHeight + 'px';
      textLayer.style.width = canvas.offsetWidth + 'px';
      pdfJS.renderTextLayer({
        textContent: textContent,
        container: textLayer,
        viewport: viewport,
        textDivs: []
      });
    });
  }
```

but I found the generate image did not show in the cavas, Am I missing something? I am sure the pdf contains the chinese words. what should I do to make the cavas render chinese normally? This is the html that shows the rendered pdf:

```
<div className={styles.cavasLayer}>
              <canvas id="the-cavas" ref={canvasRef} />
              <div className={styles.textLayer}></div>
            </div>
```

I have tried to add the cMap like this:

```
pdfJS.cMapUrl= 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/'
```

seems did not work. shows error like this:

```
index-e5fb9cea.js:201 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property cMapUrl, object is not extensible
    at m (index-e5fb9cea.js:201:22598)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found add this configuration fixed this issue:

```
const pdf = await pdfJS.getDocument({
      url: pdfUrl,
      cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/',
      cMapPacked: true,
    }).promise;
```